# Return array or multiple variables from a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, arduino, arduino-ide

```
int arrays[2] = {0,1}; 

void setup () {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(2,INPUT);
}

void loop () {

    int buttonstate = digitalRead(2); //reads I/O pin 2
    if (buttonstate==HIGH) {          //if I/O pin 2 is HIGH do following

        arrays[] = function(arrays);      //calls function "function"
        Serial.println(arrays[0]);        //prints out arrays[0]
        Serial.println(arrays[1]);        //prints out arrays[1]

    }
}

int function (int arrays [2]) {   

    int holder = arrays[1];           //switches place the values on the array
    arrays[1] = arrays[0];
    arrays[0] = holder;
    return arrays[];                  //return the modified array

}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Can someone explain why my code is wrong?
Why doesn't it just return the array and modify its content? I have read on other articles about pointers, but I couldn't understand how they worked.

Comment: you have a function declared as returning `int` and you _think you are returning an array_.  I'm afraid this is the most important error.  Also `arrays[]` is not a valid expresion, as it's not the way to refer to an array.  `[]` are only used to access elements, and you have to put an expression between them.  To return the array (case of being that possible) you should `return arrays;`, instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your worst misconception is thinking that C allows you to pass a complete array as parameter or return value.

First of all, you cannot do an assignment like

```
arrays[] = function(...);
```

This is incorrect, as there's no way to refer to the array as a whole.  You can return a *reference to an array*, something like:

```
arrays = function(...);
```

always that your function returns a valid **POINTER TO INTEGER**, and always that you declare your `arrays` variable as `int *arrays;`, instead.  But this has another problem... a pointer doesn't allocate memory for the pointed to values.

The best solution is to use the array reference to pass it to the function, and then make the function to operate on the array proper.  Like in

```
function(arrays);  /* you should have function exchanged the arrays values properly */
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) /* print arrays contents and check values have been exchanged */ 
    printf("arrays[%d] == %d\n", i, arrays[i]);
```

in this case, the `arrays()` function should have been implemented as

```
void function(int arrays[])
{
    int temporary = arrays[0];
    arrays[0] = arrays[1];
    arrays[1] = temporary;
    /* no return as function is declared void */
}
```

Of course, you can return the reference to the original array, and this can be helpful in some expressions, but think always that **you are dealing with the same array anycase**.

```
int *function(int *arrays) /* this parameter declaration is equivalent to the last one */
{
    int temporary = arrays[0];
    arrays[0] = arrays[1];
    arrays[1] = temporary;
    return arrays; /* reference to the first array element */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The array is passed to the function by reference.
If you modify the array in the function, the changes will persist after the function call.

```
int arrays[2] = {0, 1};

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(2, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

    int buttonstate = digitalRead(2); //reads I/O pin 2
    if (buttonstate == HIGH) {          //if I/O pin 2 is HIGH do following

        function(arrays);      //calls function "function"
        Serial.println(arrays[0]);        //prints out arrays[0]
        Serial.println(arrays[1]);        //prints out arrays[1]

    }
}

void function(int arrays[]) {   

    int holder = arrays[1];           //switches place the values on the array
    arrays[1] = arrays[0];
    arrays[0] = holder;

}
```

If you don't want to modify the existing array, you will need to pass another array.

```
int arrays[2] = {0, 1};
int arrays2[3];

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(2, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

    int buttonstate = digitalRead(2); //reads I/O pin 2
    if (buttonstate == HIGH) {          //if I/O pin 2 is HIGH do following

        function(arrays, arrays2);      //calls function "function"
        Serial.println(arrays2[0]);        //prints out arrays2[0]
        Serial.println(arrays2[1]);        //prints out arrays2[1]
        Serial.println(arrays2[2]);        //prints out arrays2[2]

    }
}

void function(int arrays[], int arrays_return[]) {   

    arrays_return[0] = arrays[1];
    arrays_return[1] = arrays[0];
    arrays_return[2] = arrays[0] + arrays[1];

}
```

You will need to make sure that the array have appropriate size, because there won't be any explicit error thrown if you write/read outside the array's range, but you may find some odd behavior that will be hard to debug.